# Multiple regex statements

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using multiple regex statements with `preg_replace` and found out that they work individually. Once I include more than one preg_replace, another will stop working.

Is there a way to use `preg_replace` in an ordered way, rather than as soon as it loads?

Here's what I have so far:

```
file_put_contents("$uploadedfile", preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/", "", "$filecontents"));         

file_put_contents("$uploadedfile", preg_replace('/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})/', '<em>(\1) \2-\3</em>', $filecontents));
```

Comment: In the above code, the second will run properly but not the first, however, if I remove the second statement, the first runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because filecontents which you are using in second is old one. you won't see the effect of first statement as you were not fetching the new content from file.

try this

```
file_put_contents("$uploadedfile", preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/", "", "$filecontents"));  

$filecontents = file_get_contents($uploadedfile);       

file_put_contents("$uploadedfile", preg_replace('/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})/', '<em>(\1) \2-\3</em>', $filecontents));
```

or

save everything to one temp variable and write to file at the end